# Why is sed -E find/replace showing unexpected output

Tags: sed, grep

I'm trying to extract `sha256:13b918c5a5eadfed53597146332889dc5e10d1a8edbcdc42f7a872531766aab8` from the following output. The output is in a file called `d2.txt`.

d2.txt:

```
The push refers to repository [...]
331ebf1e6bb7: Layer already exists 
9bb0b3c0e55b: Layer already exists 
9f59b9615f5e: Layer already exists 
82621df65774: Layer already exists 
3e123f0af898: Layer already exists 
93defbb4091e: Layer already exists 
bc21254008da: Layer already exists 
53619ba80b4a: Layer already exists 
18eb03bf3058: Layer already exists 
daf4ddfb16e5: Layer already exists 
b5639327d5be: Layer already exists 
30ccd09e6f92: Layer already exists 
167efff21776: Layer already exists 
fee20f1b745d: Layer already exists 
d0fe97fa8b8c: Layer already exists 
v1.0: digest: sha256:13b918c5a5eadfed53597146332889dc5e10d1a8edbcdc42f7a872531766aab8 size: 3470
```

Using grep I can use the following to identify the line with the digest:

```
grep -E '^.*(sha256:[a-z0-9]{64}).*' d2.txt
```

which returns:

```
v1.0: digest: sha256:13b918c5a5eadfed53597146332889dc5e10d1a8edbcdc42f7a872531766aab8 size: 3470
```

Using the parenthesis from this regex to define capture group 1 (the sha256:hash), I attempt to run this in sed. But Instead getting just the line with the digest, I get all the lines in d2.txt. (With the correct capture group on the sha256 line!).

```
sed -E  s/'^.*(sha256:[a-z0-9]{64}).*'/'\1'/g d2.txt
```

returns:

```
The push refers to repository [...]
331ebf1e6bb7: Layer already exists 
9bb0b3c0e55b: Layer already exists 
9f59b9615f5e: Layer already exists 
82621df65774: Layer already exists 
3e123f0af898: Layer already exists 
93defbb4091e: Layer already exists 
bc21254008da: Layer already exists 
53619ba80b4a: Layer already exists 
18eb03bf3058: Layer already exists 
daf4ddfb16e5: Layer already exists 
b5639327d5be: Layer already exists 
30ccd09e6f92: Layer already exists 
167efff21776: Layer already exists 
fee20f1b745d: Layer already exists 
d0fe97fa8b8c: Layer already exists 
sha256:13b918c5a5eadfed53597146332889dc5e10d1a8edbcdc42f7a872531766aab8
```

So why does *sed* return the full text all lines where there is no regex match?

Comment: There is a replacement, but you can use `sed -En ` for example `sed -En 's/^.*(sha256:[a-z0-9]{64}).*/\1/p' d2.txt`

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You don't tell it to do anything with it, so it prints them. You can use `-n` to suppress the output, then add `p` after the substitution to print that anyway.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Bingo! thanks. If I wanted to use global '/g' (which I don't need) I can add that too and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grep with `-o` to print only the matched part.

```
grep -Eo 'sha256:[[:alnum:]]{64}' d2.txt
```

---

Or with sed you can prevent the default printing with `-n` and use `p` to only print the line with the substitution.

```
sed -En  's/^.*(sha256:[a-z0-9]{64}).*/\1/p' d2.txt
```

Both will output

```
sha256:13b918c5a5eadfed53597146332889dc5e10d1a8edbcdc42f7a872531766aab8
```

Comment: without testing, I'd suggest `grep -E` would suffice: `grep -Eo 'sha256:[[:alnum:]]{64}' file`

Comment: @glennjackman Oh my, of course you are right. I focused on the anchor `^` but that is much easier, thanks!

Comment: Regarding @glen jackman's comment, I tried with just -E (minus the 'o') and it prints the whole line. Might have misunderstood based on an unseen edit.

Comment: That's what the `-o` does: just prints the matched text

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, in `awk` with `awk`'s `match` function you can try following code:

```
awk 'match($0,/sha256:[a-z0-9]{64}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' d2.txt
```

In case you have ONLY ONE MATCH in whole file and you want to print it then use `exit` also with above code to make this faster and we need not to read whole file then,

```
awk 'match($0,/sha256:[a-z0-9]{64}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);exit}' d2.txt
```